# GET value from html element and POST with ajax to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post, get

Fists off, I'm new to JavaScript, so please excuse my ignorance.

I have a function that accepts a parameter specified by each button.
I am trying to use PHP and AJAX to successfully query the MySQL database.

This is what I have so far:

```js
function reply_click(clicked_id) {
    var Type = clicked_id;
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'PHP_markAtype.php',
        data: {type: Type},                 
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    }); 
}
```

```html
<button class="click" name="rowID" type="submit" onClick="reply_click('dog')">Make it a dog</button>
```

Then on the server side PHP (on page PHP_markAtype.php) I have:

```php
$idAnim = $_GET["Site"];
mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);

// update type
$query = "UPDATE tableA SET Atype = '$idAnim'";
mysql_query($query);
```

Now from all the examples I have seen, this should work but I get a blank page back.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? In your php code you are updating your database, and not returning anything. Getting a blank response seems to be normal in that case.

Comment: You are using `POST` as type yet you are getting your values using `$_GET`, which one do you really use?

Comment: Why are you using the long-deprecated `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible, and then learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Well...

- Using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions instead of [`mysqli_*` functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).
- Trying to access posted data with `$_GET`.
- Leaving yourself vulnerable to [SQL injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) by not using [parametised queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

---

Now the answer.
You weren't far off the mark.

The PHP should look like this:

```
$idAnim = $_POST["animal"];

$query = $con->prepare("UPDATE tableA SET Atype = ?");
$query->bind_param("s", $idAnim);
$query->execute();

echo "Successfully updated data to $idAnim";
?>
```

Note that I haven't done any error checking here, I have left that for you.
Make sure that the `$_POST` was sent, that [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-bind-param.php) didn't fail, and that `execute` was successful.

Now for the HTML and JavaScript (JS).

```js
function reply_click(clicked_id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "PHP_markAtype.php",
        data: {animal: clicked_id},                 
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $("#test").html(data);
        }
    }); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="click" name="rowID" type="submit" onClick="reply_click('dog')">Make it a dog</button>
<div id="test"></div>
```

I have altered the JS to change a new `<div>` contents the PHP message if the data is successful.
Additionally, I have removed the pointless variable assignment of the parameter.

I hope this works for you, but *please take into consideration the comments at the top of this answer*.
There are some serious security issues in using `mysql_*` and printing the variable straight into the string.

Comment: @Jacobus No problem, I have linked plenty of documentation should you get stuck with anything.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
             $_GET["type"];
```

to

```
             $_POST["type"];
```

Comment: sweet and short, thanks. can't believe that I made that mistake. Thanks again